# Set Title of bigpicyure style notification 2 liner Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, multiline

I am able to generate notification using BigPictureStyle Notification but its title is coming only in one line but I want it to be two liner instead of continuation symbol.

Code is to set notification style big
picture

```
NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
notiStyle.setBigContentTitle(headline);
notiStyle.bigPicture(remote_picture);
```

By this code I am creating notification and setting setStyle with my bigpicture Style notification

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wrap_up_logo).setAutoCancel(true)
    .setLargeIcon(icon).setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
    .setContentTitle(headline).setStyle(notiStyle).build();
```

This is the notification i am receiving [image]

Comment: You should add your code, how should we guess what you did wrong?

Comment: @  rekire- Please see my updated Question

Comment: Did you try setting `setSummaryText()`?

Comment: Yes, it comes like subheading in single line